# How to disallow temporaries in functions taking const references?

Tags: c++, c++14, temporary

**Background:**

Lets say I have something like this:

```
struct item
{
    int x;
    item(int y): x(y) {}
}

class item_view
{
    const item& it;
public:
    item_view(const item& it_) : it(it_) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const item_view& view)
    {return os;} //actually is more complicated
}
```

The reason why I cannot just overload `operator<<` is that it is more human friendly, and view is used to pass the data to SQL, so ticks and some other characters must be escaped.

**Problem:**

Somebody might want to do something like this:

```
auto view = item_view(2);
std::cout << view;
```

This seems to be undefined behavior.

**Question:**

How can I prevent construction of `item_view` from temporaries?

Comment: Obviously? There is no UB here... The temporary constructed from `2` lives until the end of the statement.

Comment: @Quentin, good note. I believe people used it like `auto view = item_view(2); std::cout << view;` That certainly should be UB.

Comment: Yep, that time around it is :)

Comment: By the way, constructor parameter names do not need to be different from the data member names to be initialised. You can use `item(int x): x(x) {}` and `item_view(const item& it) : it(it) {}` just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can provide an additional overload that's a better matches for temporaries and then delete it. For example :

```
#include <string>

void foo(const std::string &) {}
void foo(std::string &&) = delete;

int main()
{
    std::string world = "World";
    foo("Hello");   // Doesn't compile, wants to use foo(std::string &&)
    foo(world);     // Compiles
}
```

Comment: Wow, this was simpler than I thought. Thanks.

Comment: Also, ctor of `item` should probably be explicit.

Comment: @Snps, in real code it is some user defined type. I don't have many templates lying around the codebase, so I believe it should be ok.

Comment: This may not be a good idea for converting constructors. The technique shown in [LWG 2993's PR](https://wg21.link/lwg2993) can be used instead.

Comment: And in any event, you'd want `const std::string&&` here in order to correctly reject const rvalues.

Comment: @T.C., can I just use a template and ban everything else?

Comment: @Incomputable depends on if you want implicit conversions.